# change class of a number of divs when mouseover

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a script as follows. I have a number of divs and when the cursor is over a div I change the class name of that div as follows. But I dont know the number of such divs. How can I updete the code according to that? thanks.

```
$(function() {   
    $('#ea_0').hover( function(){    
    $('#ea_0').attr('class','myClassHover'); 
    },  

    function(){       
        $('#ea_0').attr('class','myClass'); 
    }); 
}); 

<div id="ea_0" class="myClass" ></div>
<div id="ea_1" class="myClass" ></div>
<div id="ea_2" class="myClass" ></div>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
$(function () {
    $('div[id^="ea_"]').hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass('myClassHover');
        $(this).removeClass('myClass');
    }, function () {
        $(this).addClass('myClass');
        $(this).removeClass('myClassHover');
    });
});
​
```

Uses the [starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to select all DOM elements with the `id` starting `ea_` and uses [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) to switch the class attributes

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/8zUYE/)

Comment: +1 for being (much) faster, though oddly your answer didn't show at all until after I'd posted mine.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist i created it 10 mins ago - then deleted it cause it wasnt working, got it working (i was using `toggleClass`) then edited it again !

Answer (score 0):

Adding a class unique to those `<div>` elements would be the better option, if possible. If not, then you can use an "attribute starts with" selector of the ID, to select all `<div>` elements that have an ID beginning with "ea_". Then use `this` to refer to the `<div>` that triggered the event inside the callback functions.

```
$(function() {   
    $('div[id^="ea_"]').hover( function(){    
        $(this).attr('class','myClassHover'); 
    },  
    function(){       
        $(this).attr('class','myClass'); 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this elegant solution: You just have to wrap all of your divs inside another div and instead of binding the hover event to each one of them, you just have to bind the mouseover and mouseout event to the container div in order to speed up the stuff.

```
$('div:first').mouseover(function(event) {
    $(event.target).closest('div').addClass('myClassHover');
});
$('div:first').mouseout(function(event) {
    $(event.target).closest('div').removeClass('myClassHover');
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/8vD56/